# Attaching a newly generated resume from profile redirects you back to the job posting

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have recently updated my resume on Careers. I'd previously created a PDF of the old one and used for previous applications. I wanted to apply to a new position with a new PDF of the new resume.

While applying for a position on careers, in *Your Resume*, I removed an existing resume, built a new one using my Careers profile, and was kicked back to the job posting.  This wasn't what I expected. It was a bit jarring to be removed from the UI pop-up.

**Expected Behaviour**

The regenerated resume PDF would attach and send me back to the *Your Resume* section, or move me onto *Review & Send*.

**Repro Steps**

1. On a posting, click Apply Now button.
2. *About You* section. Enter your cover letter details as per normal. Click the next button.
3. *Your Resume* section. I [clicked the X to remove the old resume PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZRs7.png). I wanted to generate a new one. I clicked "attach new resume" link, successfully created a new resume PDF. I then [clicked the Attach To Job Application button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcOus.png).
4. The page redirects back to the job posting. I noticed querystring param `?_scjid=73139&p=review`
5. You now need to scroll to the bottom of the posting and click the Apply Now button to get back on track with the 3 application sections.

No state was lost, which was a relief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the `_scjid=73139` query string parameter is responsible for re-opening the apply widget. But an extra `return` statement in our javascript was preventing it from happening.

It should be all good now.

Thank you for your report!